# ARKit and Unity - How can I detect the act of hitting the AR object by a real world object from the camera?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, unity-game-engine, arkit

Think if someone in real life waved their hand and hit the 3D object in AR, how would I detect that? I basically want to know when something crosses over the AR object so I can know that something "hit" it and react.

Another example would be to place a virtual bottle on the table and then wave your hand in the air where the bottle is and then it gets knocked over.

Can this be done? If so how? I would prefer unity help but if this can only be done via Xcode and ARKit natively, I would be open to that as well.

Comment: Technologically speaking this is possible, but you would need some way of detecting a real world "object" as being something to recognize and apply a collider to. This is not going to be easy. https://xkcd.com/1425/ The only system I know of that can do anything remotely close is the HoloLens and its spacial mapping software. However, its update rate on real world volumes is very slow (any given 8cm cube is rechecked every 5 minutes, approximately).

Comment: @Draco18s Bummer. I was under the impression from the marketing hype that ARKit was supposed to solve a ton of issues for AR and make it a breeze to work with. From what I'm gathering now that I'm playing with it, all it really seems to do is detect planes for you. Vuforia seems to do more.

Comment: I'm not familiar with ARKit, but I have used Vuroria in the past. Sorry I don't have a solution.

Answer (score 1):

ARKit *does* solve a ton of issues with AR and make them a breeze to work with. Your issue just isn't one of them.

As @Draco18s notes (and emphasizes well with the xkcd link ), you've perhaps unwittingly stepped into the domain of hairy computer vision problems. You have some building blocks to work with, though: ARKit provides pixel buffers for each video frame, and the projection matrix needed for you to work out what portion of the 2D image is overlaid by your virtual water bottle.

Deciding when to knock over the water bottle is then a problem of analyzing frame-to-frame differences over time in that region of the image. (And tracking that region's movement relative to the whole camera image, since the user probably isn't holding the device perfectly still.) The amount of of analysis required varies depending on the sophistication of effect you want... a simple pixel diff might work (for some value of "work"), or there might be existing machine learning models that you could put together with Vision and Core ML...

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at ManoMotion: https://www.manomotion.com/
They're working on this issue and suppose to release a solution in form of library soon.